# 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Tags: c#, vb.net

So, I did some conversion to c# on my former system which is written on vb.net. This is a sample of my code:

> for (indx = 0; (indx <= (Dt.Rows.Count - 1)); indx++)
>
> ```
>         {
>             ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
>             lv.Text = Dt.Rows[indx].Item["ID"];
>             lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows[indx].Item["GuestFName"]);
>
>         }
> ```

I got squiggly red lines under Item and this is bothering me. I had the same error on my previous question and it was solved. But this is different to me. What seems to be the problem?

By the way this is the VB.NET code:

> For indx = 0 To Dt.Rows.Count - 1
>
> ```
>         Dim lv As New ListViewItem
>         lv.Text = Dt.Rows(indx).Item("ID")
>         lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows(indx).Item("GuestFName"))
>         lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows(indx).Item("GuestMName"))
>         lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows(indx).Item("GuestLName"))
>         lvGuest.Items.Add(lv)
> ```
>
> Next

Comment: I believe you are looking for `ItemArray`, there is no property `Item` with `DataRow`

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over again. Wait for answers.

Comment: umm.. this is actually a different scenario. The other question was answered already. But this is different.

Comment: no, it is absolutely identical.  read all the helpful comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same thing as your previous question: remove the `.Item`:

```
lv.Text = Dt.Rows[indx]["ID"];
lv.SubItems.Add(Dt.Rows[indx]["GuestFName"]);
```

When you see an `Item` property on MSDN, the square brackets are the way to access it in C#

Comment: Hey there Sir Rik! Umm.. I tried removing the .Item already and I got a new error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Read what the error says, the function you are calling is returning a object, the thing you are trying to assign it to is a string. You can't do that, it is asking you "did you mean to cast the object as a string?"

Comment: Well, I'm relatively new to C# and I had to use a converter in order to convert my vb.net codes. I have no idea what is wrong. :( Could you help me convert my vb.net codes above?

Comment: @Jhayzt - Try using the Field method of the DataRow:  `lv.Text = Dt.Rows[indx].Field<string>("ID");`

Comment: I'm sorry for asking the same question over and over. Its just that I'm new to C# and I use vb.net as my basis. :D Again, thank you for the answers! :D